# Why does Zaeed die in my Citadel: Volus Ambassador despite high reputation?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the *Mass Effect 3* mission Citadel: Volus Ambassador, why does my Zaeed die?

My reputation is very high, but the special conversation doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make him loyal in mass effect 2. This is done by completing his loyalty mission in mass effect 2, before attacking the collector base. He of course, also has to be alive by the end of said collector base mission

Comment: mmmmmmmmm that why is is going to hell :)  then why the special conversation never comes out even my reputaion is full?

Comment: If thats the case, then I'll assume that your mass effect 2 save did not include zaeed? If however, you completed mass effect 2 with zaeed loyal and alive, then I think the issue is with your mass effect 2 save that you imported to mass effect 3. The flag in the save that indicates zaeed's loyalty and unchecked must have been and still is, off.  For a work around, I can suggest using gibbed's mass effect 3 save editor to edit your mass effect 3 save so that you have a loyal zaeed instead.                 http://code.google.com/p/me3tools/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel%3A_Volus_Ambassador), if Zaeed was not loyal at the end of ME2, he will die in this mission.  If he was loyal, then he survives and becomes a war asset.